# Flutter HttpException: Connection closed while receiving data

Tags: http, dart, flutter

I am making a wallpaper app in Flutter but I get an exception when I use Image.Network() to get the images.

```
HttpException: Connection closed while receiving data
```

The files are currently stored on my system so the url is like this

```
http://10.0.2.2/wallipop/wallpapers/img/3.jpg
```

10.0.2.2 is for connecting to localhost from Android Emulator

Any help would be dearly appreciated

Comment: Any logs from the server about the request?

Comment: No. If there were any I don't how to check. The server is in PHP, if  you want I can share the code, it's only 1 file

Comment: I don't know PHP.

Comment: Did you check it on any mobile device?

Comment: No yet, going to try it when I get home.

Comment: @aksacha I tried it , it keeps giving me `Connection timed out`

Comment: I'm stuck with the same problem.

Comment: @JaswantSingh I fixed the error, the answer is below

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get rid of the error when I used images of smaller size, my earlier images were upto 2MBs but then I wrote some PHP code that automatically generated thumbnails for all my images and then I used those in my app, and haven't encountered that error ever since.

Comment: well I dont think this is a solution, as my images are around 40kbs, sometimes they are loaded, sometimes not, and sometimes only few of them. The problem is somewhere else